# How to document destructured variable with jsdoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have something like this:

```
let { total } = settings;
```

How do I document the total variable? I tried something like this:

```
/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {String} total.test
 */
let { total } = settings;
```

but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider that destructuring could declare multiple variables at once, so maybe you need to move the jsdoc inside the object braces?

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean something like that:
`let { 
    /**
     * @type {Object}
     * @property {String} total.test
     */
     totalInCart 
} = mincartSettings;`
If so, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: That's what I would have tried, but I have no idea.

Comment: No work around for this? I am also looking for how to solve this. I guess people moved to typescript instead of finding the solution.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to document an object, the simple answer is:

```js
/**
 * @type {{total: String}}
 */
let { total } = settings;
```

For details, take a look at the [JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html).

Answer (score 6):

[@Tommy-Pepsi Gaudreau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8902235/tommy-pepsi-gaudreau) was so close in his comment on the original question.

Here's an [example in the closure compiler tool @ closure-compiler.appspot.com](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520let%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257BObject%253Cstring%257Cboolean%253E%257D%2520*%252F%2520settings%2520%253D%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520let%2520str%2520%253D%2520'string'%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520let%2520bool%2520%253D%2520true%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520settings.b%2520%253D%2520bool%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520settings.s%2520%253D%2520str%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520Note%2520that%2520at%2520this%2520point%252C%2520b%2520and%2520s%2520are%2520of%2520the%2520type%2520%257Bstring%257Cboolean%257D.%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520let%2520%257B%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520*%252F%2520s%252C%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bboolean%257D%2520*%252F%2520b%2520%257D%2520%253D%2520settings%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(%257Bb%252C%2520s%257D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520But%2520now%252C%2520when%2520we%2520assign%2520the%2520wrong%2520types%252C%2520we%2520get%2520a%2520warning.%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520b%253D'warn'%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520s%253Dfalse%253B)

```
let /** @type {Object<string|boolean>} */ settings = {};
let str = 'string';
let bool = true;
settings.b = bool;
settings.s = str;

// Note that at this point, b and s are of the type {string|boolean}.

let {/** @type {string} */ s,/** @type {boolean} */ b } = settings;

console.log({b, s});

// But now, when we assign the wrong types, we get a warning.

b='warn';
s=false;
```

Number of warnings: 2

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : string
required: boolean at line 15 character 4
    b='warn';
    ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : boolean
required: string at line 16 character 4
    s=false;
    ^
```

*Edit - Sep 27, 2018*: I've reduced the amount of initial typing to ensure/clarify the types weren't being ignored, and that the warnings were coming from the types in the destructuring.

Comment: Experimentally, it seems like Typescript does not parse the tags shown in this answer -- is there an alternative syntax it understands?

Answer (score 6):

Simply inline JSDoc blocks *within* the destructuring block:

```js
const {

  /**
   * The answer to everything
   * @type {number}
   */
  a,

  /**
   * The perfect food container
   * @type {string}
   */
  b,
  
  /**
   * Some other stuff
   * @type {object}
   * @property {string} foo Random text
   * @property {boolean} baz Random flag
   */
  c
} = {a: 42, b: 'burrito', c: { foo: 'bar', baz: true }};
```

Screencast of VS Code:

[image]

Documentation generated with `yarn jsdoc file1.js`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

for any direct destructured variable you can try this workaround

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} DestructuredVariable
 * @property {string} total
 */
/** @type {DestructuredVariable} */
const {total} = getUser();
```