# How do you add a jsdoc type to a destructured variable? (VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

So I have a response object with a data property.  For this example, its data is of type text.  I want the data property, and I want VSCode to recognize it types so that I can get some of that IntelliSense love.

```
const response = await someRequest();
const {data} = response;
```

First I try:

```
const response = await someRequest();

/** @type {string} */
const {data} = response;
```

Nope, so then I try:

```
const response = await someRequest();

const {
  /** @type {string} */
  data,
} = response;
```

that didn't work either.

Then I try:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Response
 * @property {string} data
 */

/** @type {Response} */
const response = await someRequest();

const { data } = response;
```

That worked!

I'm not sure how much of a difference it makes, but I'm using VSCode September 2020 (version 1.50).

**Edits**: I changed how my question ended because it turned out that my final example actually works...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544065/how-to-document-destructured-variable-with-jsdoc link aswer your question.

Comment: @Dolly Thanks for pulling that up for me :-) so, the inline type declaration didn't work (it was essentially second attempt, but by some bizarre quirk, my final example (which your example does cover) actually worked.  I'll take it, but I don't know what changed between now and yesterday... 

I'm guessing it was either included in the September update of VSCode or (more likely) there was an error between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Response
 * @property {string} data
 */

/** @type {Response} */
const response = await someRequest();

const { data } = response;
```

I didn't think this was working, but it is, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Thanks to Dolly for her comment with [how to document a deconstructed variable with jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544065/how-to-document-destructured-variable-with-jsdoc).  It wasn't an exact fit, but it does answer my question.