# VS code Intellisense not working for mongodb models methods

Tags: javascript, mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongoose, intellisense

I am writing a resolver function wherein I am expecting the VS intellisense to give suggestions for the mongodb methods e.g. when I type models.Note I am expecting 'find', 'findById' methods from VS intellisense.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello World',
    notes: async () => {
      return await models.Note.find();
    },
    note: async (_, args) => {
      return await models.Note.findById(args.id);
    }
  },
```

Comment: If anyone knows any extension please let me know, I tried few of them but none of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to import the Note model directly.
if IntelliSense still does not work, you can use jsdoc, actually you can use it in both situations.

```js
/** @type {import("mongoose").Model} */
const Note = require("@models/note.model");

// or

/**
 * @typedef {object} DestructuredModel
 * @property {object} models
 * @property {import("mongoose").Model} models.Note
 */
/** @type {DestructuredModel} */
const { models } = require("mongoose");
```

for further [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html)

and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544065/how-to-document-destructured-variable-with-jsdoc) about jsdoc may be useful

Comment: You can try this firstly: File>Preferences>Settings then Extensions>TypeScript tab, enable 
 - TypeScript: Enable Prompt Use Workspace Tsdk
It helps also while using js